# How to write a join condition in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am trying to join two of my tables and create a new one. These two existing tables are like: NSFABSTRACTS(FILEID, WORD) and CLASS (WORD, ORG). I am trying to generate a new table NEW (FILEID, WORD, ORG). Below is my code but it gives me an error message.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP(FILEID, WORD, ORG) AS
  SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID, CLASS.ORG
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS JOIN CLASS
  WHERE NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=CLASS.WORD;
```

Error: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:

*Action:`.

I also tried to add parathesis on top of the select statement, didn't work either. Thanks.

Comment: When you use `JOIN` you need to specify the join condition using `ON` - not in the WHERE clause.

Comment: join can be build in two ways:
1. you can use table names in from clause with comma between table names and with equal condition in where clause like:

  SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID, CLASS.ORG
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS , CLASS
  WHERE NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=CLASS.WORD;

2. or by using "join" keyworrd in from clause  like:
  SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID, CLASS.ORG
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
  JOIN CLASS ON NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=CLASS.WORD;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "on" with "join":

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP(FILEID, WORD, ORG) AS
  SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID, CLASS.ORG
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
  JOIN CLASS ON NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=CLASS.WORD
```

People sometimes use an implicit join syntax, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP(FILEID, WORD, ORG) AS
  SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID, CLASS.ORG
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS, CLASS 
  WHERE NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=CLASS.WORD
```

but this is not recommended for modern SQL. You had both of these forms mixed up a bit.